# -Python- Move All PDF Files in Folder to NewDirectory Based on Matching Names, Using Glob or Shutil

Tags: python, glob, shutil

I'm trying to write code that will move hundreds of PDF files from a :/Scans folder into another directory based on the matching each client's name. I'm not sure if I should be using Glob, or Shutil, or a combination of both. My working theory is that Glob should work for such a program, as the glob module "finds all the pathnames matching a specified pattern," and then use Shutil to physically move the files?

Here is a breakdown of my file folders to give you a better idea of what I'm trying to do.

Within :/Scans folder I have thousands of PDF files, manually renamed based on client and content, such that the folder looks like this:

lastName, firstName - [contentVariable]
(repeat the above 100,000x)

Within the :/J drive of my computer I have a folder named 'Clients' with sub-folders for each and every client, similar to the pattern above, named as 'lastName, firstName'

I'm looking to have the program go through the :/Scans folder and move each PDF to the matching client folder based on 'lastName, firstName'

I've been able to write a simple program to move files between folders, but not one that will do the aforesaid name matching.

`shutil.copy('C:/Users/Kenny/Documents/Scan_Drive','C:/Users/Kenny/Documents/Clients')`

^ Moving a file from one folder to another.. quite easily done.

Is there a way to modify the above code to apply to a regex (below)?

`shutil.copy('C:/Users/Kenny/Documents/Scan_Drive/\w*', 'C:/Users/Kenny/Documents/Clients/\w*')`

EDIT: @Byberi - Something as such?

`path = "C:/Users/Kenny/Documents/Scans"
    dirs = os.path.isfile()`

This would print all the files and directories

`for file in dirs:
       print file`

`dest_dir = "C:/Users/Kenny/Documents/Clients"
for file in glob.glob(r'C:/*'):
    print(file)
    shutil.copy(file, dest_dir)`

I've consulted the following threads already, but I cannot seem to find how to match and move the files.

[Select files in directory and move them based on text list of filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37297527/select-files-in-directory-and-move-them-based-on-text-list-of-filenames)

https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

[Python move files from directories that match given criteria to new directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43381446/python-move-files-from-directories-that-match-given-criteria-to-new-directory)

https://www.guru99.com/python-copy-file.html

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/file-and-directory-operations-using-python--cms-25817

Comment: Get all file names using `os.listdir(path)` and loop over them moving files which match regex. Also, there is no regex in `shutil.copy('C:/Users/Kenny/Documents/Scan_Drive/\w*', 'C:/Users/Kenny/Documents/Clients/\w*')`

Comment: Thank you, super speedy reply. 

# Open a file ... 

path = "C:/Users/Kenny/Documents/Scans"
dirs = os.listdir(path)



Which then I would print all the files and directories:
for file in dirs:
   print file

Comment: You have to use `os.path.isfile()` to get only files. I suggest you to study [The Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/)

Comment: This question https://stackoverflow.com/q/43381446/2430448 does explain it very well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python move files from directories that match given criteria to new directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43381446/python-move-files-from-directories-that-match-given-criteria-to-new-directory)

Comment: I did check the "Python move files from directories that match given criteria to new directory" but what confused me there is that he writes the following..

for f in files:
    if f.startswith("hw") and len(f) > 2:

-- Would it be possible to rewrite '' if f.startswith("hw") '' to include a generalized expression such that I can match lastName, firstName to any given names, not exclusively "hw"

Comment: 1. I do not (and I do not want to) use regex. 2 Create another question asking just for `Would it be possible to rewrite '' if f.startswith("hw") '' to include a generalized expression such that I can match lastName, firstName to any given names, not exclusively "hw"` You may delete this question. It is not useful.